# Is it acceptable if the CLIENT_ID and the REVERSED_CLIENT_ID change in the Firebase console project?

Tags: swift, xcode

I have been developing an iOS project and using Firebase for logging in and sending push notifications to my application. My login function is working perfectly, and I was attempting to implement the push notification service from Firebase when I identified that the `CLIENT_ID` and `REVERSED_CLIENT_ID` in the `GoogleService-Info.plist` file is different from my Firebase console i.e. there are new values in `GoogleService-Info.plist` in the console. However, this change has not impacted my login function. I am confused about why this change occurred and have been unable to rectify it. Currently, I am unable to receive push notifications from Firebase on my real device in the TestFlight app (although I did receive them on my emulator using xcrun simctl push). My questions are:

Is it acceptable that the `CLIENT_ID` and `REVERSED_CLIENT_ID` have changed? If not, why is my login function still operational?

There has been a creation of another `<my_project_name>-info.plist` file which contains few more keys. I manually change the values of `CLIENT_ID` and `REVERSED_CLIENT_ID` in my `GoogleService-Info.plist` and my login too started to fail, so I reverted the change.